# Hadoop completebulkload gives RetriesExhaustedException

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I had imported a 8GB csv file with importtsv command. Then I run this command

```
./hadoop jar /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.10.jar completebulkload /app/hadoop/tmp/df/data/fb333 fb
```

after a while it gave this error below

```
ERROR mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Encountered unrecoverable error from region server
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=14, exceptions:
Wed Oct 09 22:59:34 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50334 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:36234 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:50334]
Wed Oct 09 23:00:35 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50334 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:36283 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:50334]
Wed Oct 09 23:01:37 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50334 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:36325 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:50334]
Wed Oct 09 23:02:38 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RegionTooBusyException: failed to get a lock in 60000ms
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.lock(HRegion.java:5889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.lock(HRegion.java:5875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.startBulkRegionOperation(HRegion.java:5834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.bulkLoadHFiles(HRegion.java:3628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.bulkLoadHFiles(HRegion.java:3611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.bulkLoadHFiles(HRegionServer.java:2930)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1426)

Wed Oct 09 23:03:40 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50334 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:36381 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:50334]
Wed Oct 09 23:04:42 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50334 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:36419 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:50334]
Wed Oct 09 23:05:46 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50334 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:36448 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:50334]
Wed Oct 09 23:06:51 EEST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$3@3cb075, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50334 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:36480 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:50334]
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday, after some struggle I was able to successfully generate HFiles using MapReduce and load into HBase using LoadIncrementalHFiles programmatically. So I am hoping I can help you out here.

Can you try these things first

1. Check if the HFiles have been generated in your output folder before you run the completebulkload. Lets assume your output folder was 'output' and the column family name was 'd', then you should have the HFiles in output/d/
2. If they are there, then run the completebulkload command. Lets assume you still get the above exception. Check if the HFiles are still present in the output folder. If they are not there, mostly even if the console is showing exceptions, the data would have been loaded in HBase. Check HBAse table row count.

   The reason why I am suggesting this is, I was facing a similar problem where LoadIncrementalHFiles loads the files into HBase and deletes it from the output folder but still tries to read the HFile from the output folder that could be why you are seeing 'timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read.'

If this still doesn't solve the problem please provide more logs for me to check.

Comment: I choose another way and left the command line way. Now I had done it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

That is the code sample I used for importing csv file

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class SampleUploader {

private static final String NAME = "SampleUploader";

static class Uploader extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {

    private long checkpoint = 100;
    private long count = 0;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text line, Context context)
            throws IOException {

        // Split CSV line
        String[] values = line.toString().split(",");

        String rowStr = values[0].replaceAll("\"", "");
        String titleStr = values[1].replaceAll("\"", "");
        String bodyStr = values[2].replaceAll("\"", "");
        String tagsStr = values[3].replaceAll("\"", "");

        // Extract each value
        byte[] row = Bytes.toBytes(rowStr.trim());
        byte[] title = Bytes.toBytes(titleStr);
        byte[] body = Bytes.toBytes(bodyStr);
        byte[] tags = Bytes.toBytes(tagsStr);

        Put put = new Put(row);
        try {

            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("st"), Bytes.toBytes("TITLE"), title);
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("st"), Bytes.toBytes("BODY"), body);
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("st"), Bytes.toBytes("TAGS"), tags);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("PUT EXC");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Uncomment below to disable WAL. This will improve performance but
        // means
        // you will experience data loss in the case of a RegionServer
        // crash.
        // put.setWriteToWAL(false);

        try {
            context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(row), put);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("WRITE EXC");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Set status every checkpoint lines
        if (++count % checkpoint == 0) {
            context.setStatus("Emitting Put " + count);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Job configuration.
 */
public static Job configureJob(Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    Path inputPath = new Path("/home/coder/Downloads/Train3.csv");
    String tableName = "sodata";
    Job job = new Job(conf, NAME + "_" + tableName);
    job.setJarByClass(Uploader.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Uploader.class);

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(tableName, null, job);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    return job;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:54310");
    conf.set("hbase.client.write.buffer", "1000000000"); //This is set high not to miss any line due to memory restrictions.
    Job job = configureJob(conf);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```